# How to get location of no-null elements in a numpy 2D array?

Tags: python, numpy

I created an array like this
`a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,np.NaN,8]])`
Which would shows up like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbPCE.png)

Now I want to get the location of null value in the array. Can anyone recommend a solution for this?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour),
read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.argwhere` with `np.isnan`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,np.NaN,8]]) 
print(np.argwhere(np.isnan(a)))

# [[1 2]]
```